# How to convert a for loop to a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a nested for loop and I'd like to convert it to a list comprehension in python. How can I do that

```
all_combinations = []
for i in range(0,size):
    for j in range(i,size):
        if i!=j:
            all_combinations.append((i,j))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_combinations = [(i,j)  for i in range(size) for j in range(i,size) if i!=j]
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers answer your question, but I'd like to suggest a better alternative, `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

print(list(combinations(range(3), 2)))
# [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Why is it better?

- There is no repetition. We specify `range(3)` only once.
- It is tested, standard library code.
- Shorter and more readable.
- (If using CPython, which you probably are) It is implemented in C which means it is (usually) faster than nested Python loops.

Comment: yes, itertools is the way. I just post as list comprehension  because the question: _"I'd like to convert it to a list comprehension in python"_

Comment: @daniherrera Fair enough, but I felt obligated to at least show the OP a better way to achieve what they are trying to do. This is essentially an XY problem

Comment: I agree with this approach.

Comment: I miss: `why is not better`: only is better if you are making `combinations`, if your post is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) abstraction of a complex problem where `combinations` don't solve your requirements you need to learn list comprehension ;)

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
all_combinations = [ (i,j) for i in range(0,size) for j in range(i,size) if i!=j ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
all_combinations = [(i,j)  for i in range(size) for j in range(i+1,size) ]
```

Don't need an if test because this will never include `(i,i)`

Comment: It has sense, I [posted direct translation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348757/842935) because I thought  this was a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a real complex problem.